# How to make batch file run from group policy?

Tags: batch-file, group-policy

I am trying to make a batch file that calls an executable named `idlelogoff` after a certain amount of idle time. I can see the process in task manager however the computer doesn't sign out.

However when I run the process as an administrator manually it works. I thought the system account was supposed to have all privileges. Very confused as to why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my batch file contents.

```
start "IdleLogOff" /d C:\ /b idlelogoff.exe  10 logoff
```

Comment: Where is `idlelogoff.exe` located? what about providing its full path rather than its file name only?

Comment: is it located under C so the path would be C:\idlelogoff.exe

Comment: So: `start "IdleLogOff" /d C:\ /b C:\idlelogoff.exe 10 logoff` (I think the path after the `/d` switch is just the working directory but is not used to find the `.exe` file)...

Comment: the batch file works when you run it so i doubt its a problem with the syntax for whatever reason it worked under local group policy but not under domain which is ok because i only need it for conference room computers. When users dont log out it creates issues with skype -__-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this by using local group policy instead of domain policy . I used user configuration->windows settings-> and then logon scripts and had it run on an user logon. The script works from here but did not work from domain group policy for whatever reason

Comment: You can also use domain policies. It's under user configuration -> policies -> windows settings -> scripts (logon/logoff).
Note it is not enough (for me at least) to just click add and browse to your batch file. I needed to click "show files" at the bottom, copy my batch file into that folder, then add and just enter the bare filename.

Answer (score 0):

look into taskmanager- i suppose that the process runs under system-account when using domain-gpo- no matter if activated/linked in user or workstation context.
So the exe would check if the system-account is idle.

A solution could be putting the exe into autostart-folder or create a run-key into registry or with an scheduled task -> all can be done with a gpo

Comment: the best way i have found was the answer above or task scheduler !